# Closed linear subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

If $H$ is a Hilbert space, and if 
$$(a,b)_H=0$$
for every $b \in B \subset H$, where $B$ is a closed linear subset of $H$, does it follow that $a=0$, the zero element of $H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because if $B\neq H$, $B$ will have a non-zero orthogonal complement. That means precisely that there exist non-zero $a\in H$ such that $(a,B)=0$.

For an extreme example, just take $B=0$ in a non-zero Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks, if $B$ were dense subset then it is true, no?

Comment: Yes. The function $v\mapsto(a,v)$ is a continuous conjugate linear form on $H$, so its kernel is closed. Therefore if the kernel contains a dense subset, it is identically zero, and in particular, $(a,a)=0$ implies $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, take $H=\Bbb R^2$, $B=\{(0,a)\mid a\in \Bbb R\}$, and $a=(1,0)$.